# Require username at registration

Tags: devise

Ive been searching and cant seem to find a question that answers this. Im pretty new to devise. Ive added a username column to my users model, and added the username field to the registration form.

But how can I require that the username field be filled out upon registration? Also check thats its unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the login to be by username (and not the devise-default email), Ryan Bates has you covered in his [RailsCasts episode # 210 : Customizing Devise](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/210-customizing-devise) See the last section on Customizing the Login Requirements.

If however, username is an additional field in the User table, add it as attr_accessible and write normal rails validations. Example:

```
validates :username, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
```

It might require some customization of the views as well to standarize the validation errors display.

Comment: Ya i followed the rails cast but he never covered how to make it required at registration. Where do i put your example? in the user model?

Comment: Yes, it will be in the user model. [RailsGuides on Active Record Validations and Callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html) has more details.